# I've got a problem while using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I've got a problem while using react hooks.

```
const { formData, onChange, errors } = useContext(ResearchTaskContext);
const [annotations, setAnnotations] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    onChange('formData.expenses.annotations', annotations);
}, [annotations]);
```

As you can see, when I change local state, need to change context state too. This is creating mode. Now I need fetch and prefilled the data for updating mode. in order to do it, I've added new useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setAnnotations(formData.expenses.annotations);
}, [formData.expenses.annotations]);
```

But this code occur too many renders.
All context states are empty initially, so if I remove dependencies, fetch data can't affect.

Comment: Your second useEffect changes your state, so the first useEffect is triggered, which changes your context, which triggers the second useEffect, which is changing your state, which triggers the first useEffect,... and so on :)

Comment: I knew that. what is the best solution for this?

Comment: I don't think you need a state, simply use your context?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially creating an infinite loop, I'd recommend to do away with annotations state as a whole, and use the formData.expenses.annotations as your source of truth.

Comment: something like this?

<Input
 value={formData.expenses.annotations}
 onChange={e => onChange('expenses.annotations', e.target.value)}
/>

Comment: Yeah, something like that. If it's slow, there might be extra you need to do with debouncing, but that can get more complicated to set up.

Comment: how to do when you need to update more complex state, such as an array or object?

Comment: Same way you did for the FormData. That's already a complex state object. But the main answer is: immutably.